# How to bundle Python Lambda inside Azure Agents Docker container

Tags: python, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using Azure DevOps Selfhosted Agents on a docker container using AWS EC2 Instances.

The agents and pipelines work fine but when I tried to deploy a lambda function using cdk deploy within these agent container I got an error.

The CDK seems to start an extra docker container inside the agent-docker-container to bundle the lambda function. But the "inner" docker container cant find the requirements.txt file. We have already spent hours trying to fix the problem but did not find any solution.

Dockerfile for the "outer" Agent Container:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade -y

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https \
    apt-utils \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    git \
    iputils-ping \
    jq \
    lsb-release \
    software-properties-common \
    nodejs \
    npm \
    docker.io

RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash

RUN npm cache clean -f
RUN npm install -g n
RUN n stable
RUN npm install -g projen
RUN npm install -g aws-cdk

# Can be 'linux-x64', 'linux-arm64', 'linux-arm', 'rhel.6-x64'.
ENV TARGETARCH=linux-x64

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "./start.sh" ]
```

How we start the container:

```
docker run -d -e AZP_URL={} -e AZP_TOKEN={} -e AZP_AGENT_POOL_NAME={} -e AZP_AGENT_NAME={} -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock dockeragent:latest
```

Heres the error from the pipeline:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:2
`),localBundling=options.local?.tryBundle(bundleDir,options),!localBundling){const assetStagingOptions={sourcePath:this.sourcePath,bundleDir,...options};switch(options.bundlingFileAccess){case bundling_1.BundlingFileAccess.VOLUME_COPY:new asset_staging_1.AssetBundlingVolumeCopy(assetStagingOptions).run();break;case bundling_1.BundlingFileAccess.BIND_MOUNT:default:new asset_staging_1.AssetBundlingBindMount(assetStagingOptions).run();break}}}catch(err){const bundleErrorDir=bundleDir+"-error";throw fs.existsSync(bundleErrorDir)&&fs.removeSync(bundleErrorDir),fs.renameSync(bundleDir,bundleErrorDir),new Error(`Failed to bundle asset ${this.node.path}, bundle output is located at ${bundleErrorDir}: ${err}`)}if(fs_1.FileSystem.isEmpty(bundleDir)){const outputDir=localBundling?bundleDir:AssetStaging.BUNDLING_OUTPUT_DIR;throw new Error(`Bundling did not produce any output. Check that content is written to ${outputDir}.`)}}calculateHash(hashType,bundling,outputDir){if(hashType==assets_1.AssetHashType.CUSTOM||hashType==assets_1.AssetHashType.SOURCE&&bundling){const hash=crypto.createHash("sha256");return hash.update(this.customSourceFingerprint??fs_1.FileSystem.fingerprint(this.sourcePath,this.fingerprintOptions)),bundling&&hash.update(JSON.stringify(bundling)),hash.digest("hex")}switch(hashType){case assets_1.AssetHashType.SOURCE:return fs_1.FileSystem.fingerprint(this.sourcePath,this.fingerprintOptions);case assets_1.AssetHashType.BUNDLE:case assets_1.AssetHashType.OUTPUT:if(!outputDir)throw new Error(`Cannot use \`${hashType}\` hash type when \`bundling\` is not specified.`);return fs_1.FileSystem.fingerprint(outputDir,this.fingerprintOptions);default:throw new Error("Unknown asset hash type.")}}}_a=JSII_RTTI_SYMBOL_1,AssetStaging[_a]={fqn:"aws-cdk-lib.AssetStaging",version:"2.78.0"},AssetStaging.BUNDLING_INPUT_DIR="/asset-input",AssetStaging.BUNDLING_OUTPUT_DIR="/asset-output",AssetStaging.assetCache=new cache_1.Cache,exports.AssetStaging=AssetStaging;function renderAssetFilename(assetHash,extension=""){return`asset.${assetHash}${extension}`}function determineHashType(assetHashType,customSourceFingerprint){const hashType=customSourceFingerprint?assetHashType??assets_1.AssetHashType.CUSTOM:assetHashType??assets_1.AssetHashType.SOURCE;if(customSourceFingerprint&&hashType!==assets_1.AssetHashType.CUSTOM)throw new Error(`Cannot specify \`${assetHashType}\` for \`assetHashType\` when \`assetHash\` is specified. Use \`CUSTOM\` or leave \`undefined\`.`);if(hashType===assets_1.AssetHashType.CUSTOM&&!customSourceFingerprint)throw new Error("`assetHash` must be specified when `assetHashType` is set to `AssetHashType.CUSTOM`.");return hashType}function calculateCacheKey(props){return crypto.createHash("sha256").update(JSON.stringify(sortObject(props))).digest("hex")}function sortObject(object){if(typeof object!="object"||object instanceof Array)return object;const ret={};for(const key of Object.keys(object).sort())ret[key]=sortObject(object[key]);return ret}function singleArchiveFile(directory){if(!fs.existsSync(directory))throw new Error(`Directory ${directory} does not exist.`);if(!fs.statSync(directory).isDirectory())throw new Error(`${directory} is not a directory.`);const content=fs.readdirSync(directory);if(content.length===1){const file=path.join(directory,content[0]),extension=getExtension(content[0]).toLowerCase();if(fs.statSync(file).isFile()&&ARCHIVE_EXTENSIONS.includes(extension))return file}}function determineBundledAsset(bundleDir,outputType){const archiveFile=singleArchiveFile(bundleDir);switch(outputType===bundling_1.BundlingOutput.AUTO_DISCOVER&&(outputType=archiveFile?bundling_1.BundlingOutput.ARCHIVED:bundling_1.BundlingOutput.NOT_ARCHIVED),outputType){case bundling_1.BundlingOutput.NOT_ARCHIVED:return{path:bundleDir,packaging:assets_1.FileAssetPackaging.ZIP_DIRECTORY};case bundling_1.BundlingOutput.ARCHIVED:if(!archiveFile)throw new Error("Bundling output directory is expected to include only a single archive file when `output` is set to `ARCHIVED`");return{path:archiveFile,packaging:assets_1.FileAssetPackaging.FILE,extension:getExtension(archiveFile)}}}function getExtension(source){for(const ext of ARCHIVE_EXTENSIONS)if(source.toLowerCase().endsWith(ext))return ext;return path.extname(source)}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ^
Error: Failed to bundle asset userautomationFunctionsStack/ActivateDisabledUserFunction/Code/Stage, bundle output is located at /azp/_work/1/s/cdk.out/asset.53c07242de0fb99436499a82683dbd5638071df75c35426fa37d2a557697abbd-error: Error: docker exited with status 1
--> Command: docker run --rm -u "0:0" -v "/azp/_work/1/s/lib/userAutomation/lambda:/asset-input:delegated" -v "/azp/_work/1/s/cdk.out/asset.53c07242de0fb99436499a82683dbd5638071df75c35426fa37d2a557697abbd:/asset-output:delegated" -w "/asset-input" cdk-58484834897f41f81a68b0701fdfab3ab071f876fb12fea79e4316889d01136f bash -c "rsync -rLv /asset-input/ /asset-output && cd /asset-output && python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output"
    at AssetStaging.bundle (/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:2:603)
    at AssetStaging.stageByBundling (/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:4544)
    at stageThisAsset (/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:2005)
    at Cache.obtain (/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/cache.js:1:242)
    at new AssetStaging (/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:2400)
    at new Asset (/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3-assets/lib/asset.js:1:736)
    at AssetCode.bind (/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda/lib/code.js:1:4628)
    at new Function (/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda/lib/function.js:1:7479)
    at new PythonFunction (/azp/_work/1/s/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-lambda-python-alpha/lib/function.ts:73:5)
    at UserautomationFunctionsStack.createLambdaFunction (/azp/_work/1/s/lib/userAutomation/UserautomationFunctionsStack.ts:241:12)
[15:22:01] Notices refreshed
```

we spent hours trying to fix the problem but nothing seems to work. Thank you for any help!